# Can a 5th degree equation with repeated roots be solved by radicials?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, radicals

I realized that generally a 5th degree equation cannot be solved by radicals, but what if we have a 5th degree equation with repeated roots, how about its solvability by radicals? Intuitively, it would be like an equation with lower degree while those equations can be solved by radicals; specifically, would there be a 4th degree equation sharing the same roots with the 5th equation with a doube root?

Comment: Any irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ (or, e.g., any other field of characteristic $0$) has distinct roots.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: you can find the repeated factor by applying Euclid's algorithm to the polynomial and its derivative, then divide by this factor to get at worst a quartic.

---

Indeed, here is an even easier method: a repeated root is also a root of the derivative. The derivative is a quartic. So we can find the roots of the derivative, then check which are also roots of the original polynomial. Dividing $x-a$ where $a$ is a repeated root will yield a quartic with the same roots, while dividing by the gcd of the polynomial and its derivative will give a polynomial that is at worst quartic with no repeated roots.

Comment: But since the factor is repeated, you can divide by it twice, leaving at worst a cubic!

Comment: thanks a lot. it's crystal clear